# MKMapView init exception

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mkmapview, mapkit

we use no storyboard for this particular controller

- Targeting iOS 10 +
- Using Cocoapods for dependecy management
- Mapkit is linked.
- Runs fine on Simulator

let `mapView = MKMapView()` // the line which produces exception

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty
array'
 First throw call stack: (0x188172fd8 0x186bd4538 0x1880511f0 0x18fe3c424 0x18fe3bc70 0x18fe3b270 0x18fe3c9a0 0x18fe3c9d0
 0x18fea4870 0x18fea7214 0x1017a5a10 0x1017a6778 0x18fea71ac
 0x19483d514 0x194827898 0x10013f878 0x10013908c 0x10013e074
 0x10013e324 0x10003a264 0x100038848 0x10017fa9c 0x1001820c8
 0x10017f688 0x100175874 0x1001747d4 0x100174870 0x18e3ccf28
 0x18e47cca8 0x18e52ea18 0x18e520ab4 0x18e294724 0x1881209a0
 0x18811e628 0x18811ea74 0x18804ed94 0x189ab8074 0x18e307130
 0x10012c860 0x18705d59c)
```

I tried creating another controller with `MKMapView` member - same issue.

Tried on new project - working fine.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/80856#80856 is a similar issue but not exact one.

issue came up recently only, any clues?

Comment: Show the code where this crash occurred in context; the exception is pretty clear; you tried to access the first element of an empty array.

Comment: I didn't. Exception come from the MKMapView init()

Comment: Please show more context for this code.

Comment: ```final class StoreDetailViewController: UIViewController {
   let mapView = MKMapView()
    let callButton = UIButton()
    let directionsButton = UIButton()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
    }
    func setupViews(){
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        title = NSLocalizedString("Store Details", comment: "Store Details")
        ...
    ```
Call never reaches viewDidLoad()

Comment: FYI - signing is managed by XCode.

Comment: Tried changing the Bundle id to a non existing one and tried again. It works. But how can the provisioning profile affect the MapKit ?

Comment: It is saying array beyond range exception. It may not be related to MKMapView.

Comment: What happens if you delete the app from the device and reinstall it?

Comment: same.tried re-building, pod install etc. Seems to be connected some way with the specific app id/ provisioning profile...